# UIButton at left or right edge of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton

In a UITableView, I want to display 2 buttons in each cell, one at the far left, the other at the far right. I have this mostly working, but I have 2 problems.

1: similar to [How do I adjust the left margin for prototype cells in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26107188/1449799), my button is stopped with a margin on the left (oddly not on the right?). When I adjust the contentInset as suggest in this question, i then get a margin on the left, but when i `self.playlistsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, -15)` i still get a margin on the right.

2: because of the margin in 1, if the user manages somehow to tap between the edge of my left button, and the edge of the screen (in the left margin), the tableviewcell is tapped.

I really don't care to visually change what I have, but i don't want the user to be able to click in the margin. the cell should be click able, but only if they click on the many pixels between the left an right justified buttons.

How do i prevent the margin from registering the tap? Or do I somehow make the button hang off into the margin so that it will get margin taps? if the answer is to get rid of the margin, how do i prevent it from then appearing on the right?